# EXCEL VBA: Suspended 'For Loops'

Tags: excel, vba, loops, exit

General Question...

What dangers exist if I suspend/exit/interrupt a 'For' loop in my VBA Code (Excel based)?

Here is my code:

```
For i = 1 to Sheets.Count

    'check stuff
    'do stuff

    if MsgBox("blah blah", vbyesnocancel, "blah") = vbyes then
       'do stuff
        GoTo loopescape
    End if

Next

loopescape:

'rest of code
```

Basically, I have my code constructed in a way that exits a for loops prematurely (based on a user's input). I am just wondering if this will leave my program susceptible to crashes (or other dangers).

So, do you think interrupting/suspending/exiting a 'for' loop could be problematic?

Thanks,

Elias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fine. It's okay to use GoTo to exit a loop. It's not okay to use GoTo to jump *in* to a 'For' loop though. (Jumping in, depending on the loop variable data type, seems to produce either a run-time error saying the 'For' loop is not initialized, or to silently fail to loop around.)

But you don't need to use GoTo to exit. This is exactly what the `Exit For` statement is for:

```
If MsgBox("blah blah", vbYesNoCancel, "blah") = vbYes Then
   'do stuff
    Exit For
End If
```